# Showing an alert dialog with an expand-and-crossfade animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-alertdialog, flutter-dialog, flutter-material

I would like to show an [`AlertDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) with an ["expand and cross-fade"](https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/demystifying-the-material-design-expand-and-cross-fade-effect-67787306630c) transition originating from the widget that is tapped to open it.

[image: Example of transition]

Does Flutter provide APIs for this transition, or does it need to be implemented manually? If the latter, how?